# Ajax calendar (background always transparent )

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax

I have a problem in Ajax calendar background, i can't remove the transparent background, the label under the calenderextender appear via the calenderextender 
i try the following but nothing help

1. change EnableEventValidation
2. put calender in div with white background
3. change Z-Index to max value
4. make css class for calender Extender with all required value but BackGround has no effect
5. check in web.config file

   ```
   <pages enableEventValidation="true">
       <controls>
           <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
       </controls>
   </pages>
   ```
6. check if the following script exists in page source :

   ```
   <script src="/AJAXTimer/ScriptResource.axd?d=9tk5luWIQHpRBi2jvaLA3ovu_ryV3iBlv84cuaA3MT--_
   e3q9KdLubgmmRoMp9ixegSpkyQ0LFGM_KxDw2qwSneq8GS2D1TcTOujL7Q85DE1&amp;t=556b0a58" 
   type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```

any ideas about this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729392/net-ajax-calendarextender-cuts-of-saturdays-in-ie7-works-fine-in-firefox;
http://tonesdotnetblog.wordpress.com/2009/05/09/how-to-style-the-ajax-control-toolkit-calendar-extender-control/;
http://kajaxnet.blogspot.com/2008/04/custom-css-for-calendar-extender-ajax.html

Comment: i tried that but nothing help :( thank very much

Comment: it was Css problem Css classes overlapped and corrupted Z-Index Effect